# Testing node tcp server with mocha

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, testing, tcp, mocha.js

I have a tcp server that I'd like to test with mocha:

```
// Start the server
require('net').createServer(function (socket) {
  // Handle incoming data
  socket.on('data', function (data) {
     ... some stuff
     socket.write("reply with some err message if any");
  });
});
```

I usually develop node application with expressjs for HTTP Rest API, and uses grunt-express-server module, such as:

```
grunt.registerTask('validate', [
    'express:dev',
    'mochaTest',
    'express:dev:stop'
]);
```

This runs the express server, runs the test and stop the express server.
Is there the same kind of stuff to test tcp server ?

Answer (score 3):

Sure is. You can test whatever you want with Mocha. Something like the following should work:

```
describe('Test tcp server', function () {

    it('Should reply with some err message if any', function (done) {

        // Set up a client and connect to port 31337 (or whatever port you use)
        var client = net.connect({ port: 31337 },
            function() {
                // Send some data
                client.write('Let's send this data!');
            }
        );

        // When data is returned from server
        client.on('data', function(data) {
            // Let's make sure data equals the correct message
            data.should.equal('reply with some err message if any');
            client.end();
            done();
        }); 

    });

});
```

Comment: thanks, that's really help, but how do you start and stop the server directly at the beginning of the test suite and stop it when all the tests are done ? Any grunt module simiral to the one used to test express server ?